# Show that $x^x$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Define $f\colon\mathbb R_{+} \to \mathbb R, x\mapsto x^x$.

Show that $x^x$ is differentiable.

---

$x^x = e^{x\ln(x)}$

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{(x+h)\ln(x+h)} - e^{x\ln(x)}}{h} = \dots$

I calculated the derivative, which should be $e^{x\ln(x)}(\ln(x)+1) = x^x\cdot(\ln(x)+1)$. But how do I get here using the differential equation?

Edit:

The full question was: Show that $x^x$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative. I already calculated its derivative so I didn't mention it in the question.

It's not required to use the limit. I tried using it since it was the definition of the derivative in the text book.Any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have to use the limit definition? Usually, it's easier to use some properties like the composition of differentiable functions is differentiable.

Comment: In the title, you just ask to prove that $f$ is differentiable, which doesn’t require to compute the derivative. In the body of the question, you try to compute the derivative using a limit. And also speak of a differential equation without telling us the link with the computation of the derivative of $f$. Can you fix all that telling us precisely what you need to do?

Comment: I have to show that x^x is differentiable and calculate its derivative. I've already calculated its derivative, so I didn't mention it in the question. I tried using the definition using the limit, that's why I used it. So it's not required to use it, I just thought this might be the right way.

Comment: The rules that you used to calculate the derivative, if you can prove those rules, then you have proved that the function is differentiable. So the question is, how did you calculate the derivative, and how do you know that the method you used is legitimate?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f: \mathbb{R}_{+}\to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=x^{x}$. Since that $$f(x)=x^{x}=\exp\left(x\ln(x)\right),$$is the composition of differentiable functions, hence $f$ is a differentiable function.

On the other hand,  setting $y:=x^{x}$, so we have that
$$\ln(y)=\ln(x^{x})$$
$$\ln(y)=x\ln(x)$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{1}{x}+\ln(x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{x}(1+\ln(x)).$$
Therefore, $$f'(x)=x^x(1+\ln(x)).$$

Answer (score 3):

Let us first simplify the exponent of the first term in the numerator:
$$(x+h)\ln (x+h) = x\ln x + h \ln x + x \ln (1 + \frac{h}{x}) + h \ln (1 + \frac{h}{x})$$

Using the expansion of $\ln (1 + x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \ldots$, we get
$$(x+h)\ln (x+h) = x\ln x + h \ln x + \left(h - \frac{h^2}{2x} + \ldots\right) + \left(\frac{h^2}{x} - \frac{h^3}{2x^2} + \ldots\right)$$

Now, using this in the limit and taking $e^{x\ln x}$ common from both the terms in numerator we have
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{(x+h)\ln (x+h)} - e^{x \ln x}}{h} = x^x\left( \frac{e^{h \ln x +h + \frac{h^2}{2x}} - 1}{h}\right)$$
Now, we know that $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots$

Therefore,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{(x+h)\ln (x+h)} - e^{x \ln x}}{h} = x^x\left( \frac{(1 + h\ln x + h + \frac{h^2}{2x} + \ldots ) - 1}{h}\right)$$
which gives
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{(x+h)\ln (x+h)} - e^{x \ln x}}{h} = x^x(\ln x + 1)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Using well known theorems on differentiable maps**

$f(x)=x^x=e^{x \ln x}$ is the composition of $x \mapsto e^x$ and $x \mapsto x \ln x$, which is differentiable as the product of two differentiable maps. Therefore $f$ is differentiable.

And you computed the derivative.